# Git: remove -f and --force branches

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I've accidentally created `-f` and `--force` branches in my local git repository. Well, second one wasn't accidentally to tell the truth.

Now I want to remove them, but `git branch` recognizes `-f` and `--force` as options, and doesn't delete them.

I think that editing some files or folders in `.git` might be helpful, but I'm not sure. How do I delete such branches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `git branch -d -- -f`

The `--` tells git it's a name and you can use it in other places around git

Comment: More specifically, the `--` tells git you're done including options, so the next $ARG will be an argument, not an option, regardless of how it starts.